# Setting up an IRC server with persistent chat history and timestamps on Raspbian?

Tags: linux, logging, history, raspberry-pi, irc

I have bought a Raspberry Pi which I intend to use as a 24/7 IRC server, probably [using IRCD-Hybrid](http://raspberrypihelp.net/tutorials/17-raspberry-pi-irc-server).
Ideally, this server would have a persistent chat history (where new people joining the channel(s?) should automatically see the chat's last `x` messages) as well as working timestamps. If possible, users would be able to see this chat history regardless of the IRC client they're using, but if this requires me to host some sort of modified web client alongside the IRC server then that's no problem.

I have seen several similar questions on SU (see [this](https://superuser.com/questions/636414/how-to-see-chat-history-in-irc-channel) and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/279598/corporate-authenticated-timestamped-logged-persistent-multi-user-chat-irc)), but I was wondering if this is specifically possible in Linux with a self-hosted IRC server, and if so, how best to do it.

Any advice would be immensely appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IRC itself doesn't record chat history, it only forwards messages between users.  Some ircd's may have a logging facility that dumps every message going past it, but unless you have IRC bots running in every channel, which is not a feasible or scalable solution when any user can create their own channels, "replaying" the channel history to users is not possible.

A bouncer can do this, but this is something that typically the end user has complete control over, if you're wanting to keep chat logs for auditing purposes or something like that.

However, PHP Free Chat works like you want, only requires Apache and PHP, and the end user doesn't have to worry about installing a client.

Comment: InspIRCd has this feature, but timestamps are impossible.

Comment: I ended up using InspIRCd and KiwiIRC (a web client you can host yourself), and I've got serverside chat history and clientside timestamps working.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't know InspIRCd timestamped and retained history, that's good info. :)